# How to get rid of an error message from 'deoplete'

Tags: error, plugin-deoplete, message

Every time I run `vim` I receive the following error message that disappear afterwords. What can I do to get rid of that message or to get rid of the problem?

```
[deoplete] [yarp] [deoplete] job is dead. failed establishing channel for ['python3', '-u', '/home/sb/.vim/plugged/nvim-yarp/pythonx/yarp.py', '/tmp/vxXiDJM/0', 2, 'deoplete']
[deoplete] function deoplete#enable[9]..deoplete#initialize[1]..deoplete#init#_initialize[15]..deoplete#init#_channel[24]..yarp#core#notify[1]..yarp#core#wait_channel, line 13
```

Comment: Best is to file with deoplete author—theyll be able to help you debug the issue. In the meantime, you could disable deoplete to make the error go away, but you’ll lose the functionality

Comment: Thank you. I disabled it with `let g:deoplete#enable_at_startup = 0`.

Comment: please post your solution as an answer, so that it does not get lost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and fixed with `pip install --user pynvim`

Comment: Welcome to this site :) Note that OP fixed their issue with `let g:deoplete#enable_at_startup = 0` (they should have posted it as an answer). Also it would be worth adding to your answer that before trying to install `pynvim` one should check `:checkhealth` which will say if `pynvim` or other dependencies are needed.